# What licenses and registrations are required to start a home business repackaging food in NY?

Tags: united-states, business, new-york-state, food-processing

I'd like to start a home business repackaging food in New York State in the US.  For example, let's say I'm buying 10kg bags of rice from the supermarket and I want to put them into jars each containing 250g.

I started on the assumption that the state would not approve if I started doing that without any permits, so I went to Google.

The New York State Small Business Development Center has [a guide](http://www.nyssbdc.org/resources/Publications/foodproducts.pdf) that I think addresses this very issue.  This suggests on page 55 that, to start a home food business in New York, I need a [20-C license](http://www.agriculture.ny.gov/FS/consumer/processor.html) from the Department of Agriculture, and also that I don't need to register with the FDA as I'm operating from my home.

I also found [this page](http://www.health.ny.gov/environmental/indoors/food_safety/regs.htm) at the Department of Health, but it seems to be a registration system for restaurants, not food processors.

So, is the 20-C all I need for home food reprocessing?  Or am I better off [scheduling a meeting](http://www.nyssbdc.org/Start.aspx) with the Small Business Development Corporation and then self-answering this question?

Comment: If this can be edited into a more general question, please feel free to do so - I want this to be useful for everyone in NY who wants to start a similar business.

Comment: Good research so far!  I would recommend you take that meeting and then self-answer the question.

Comment: Not sure so didn't answer but what about the following:
Food Service Establishment (FSE) permit,
Food Processor license,
U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) Food Facility Registration,
Label Approval.